# Setting the target on an internal link field

Tags: content-editor, links

Is the link target dropdown editable somewhere in the Sitecore tree?

On a Sitecore v8.0 (rev. 150812) system, when editing a General Link field, the content editor is unable to set the "target" property for the link:

[image: Content Editor]

On the resulting dialog, there is no "none" on the Target drop down:

[image: Link Editor]

Selecting "Active Browser" and then rendering the field via a standard field renderer:

```razor
foreach (Item menuItem in topMenu.Children)
{
    <li>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Link", menuItem)</li>
}
```

results in the following markup:

```html
<a href="/products" target="Active Browser">Products</a>
```

I'm assuming the list of link targets is somewhere core database? I'm able to correct the target by editing the raw values, but want to make sure my content editors don't run into this issue again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue with the `General Link Field`. To fix it open the **Core** database and navigate too:

`/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/TargetsSearchPanelConfig`

In there, find the `Filters` section and then the `Root` field. Change the field to point at: `/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/System/Texts/Targets`

[image]

After you have done this, the list in the `General Link Field` will show the values:

- Select a target
- _blank
- _parent
- _top

[image]

> *NOTE* - this will *not* fix your existing link fields. You will have to go back and edit the existing fields and select one of the values to remove the `Active Browser` target

Answer (score 6):

This is a know bug, please perform the following steps in the "core" database:

1) Navigate to the "/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog/PageSettings/TargetsSearchPanelConfig" item.

2) In the "Root" field of the "Filters" section, specify the "sitecore/client/Business Component Library/System/Texts/Targets" item.

After this change, links should be generated with correct targets.

Comment: Ha - took me longer to write my answer! Just a note on this - making that change will _not_ fix any of the existing links - it will only allow the user to select a valid value for the link target. The editor must sill revisit all existing link fields and update them.

Comment: @RichardSeal yep you are right about existing links