# Target attribute on external link is not getting rendered

Tags: links

I'm working on Sitecore 8.0 rev. **151127**. I have tried all the options provided in question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921649/external-general-link-open-in-new-window)

However I am unable to get target attribute render in anchor tag. When I see the raw values for the link I can see the target is set to "_blank"

**Update**
[image]

[image]

After publishing when, I see the link, there is no target attribute set in anchor.[image]

Comment: Can you post your code? and raw value of the field?

Comment: @MarekMusielak updated my question

Comment: And what is the code used to render this link?

Comment: Question is marked as duplicate. Have you tried the solutions suggested on that question? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/setting-the-target-on-an-internal-link-field

Comment: @MarekMusielak you are right! the rendering was hardcoded as anchor tag. not using Sitecore field render.